FirebaseMessagingError: An unknown server error was returned. Raw server response: ""DeprecatedApi""
I tried to configure node js server with firebase fcm cloud messaging and when i try to send message i have response from server:
FirebaseMessagingError: An unknown server error was returned. Raw server response: ""DeprecatedApi""
    at FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:269:16)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:94:65
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at mapRawResponseToDevicesResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:90:26)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:484:24

i use the latest "firebase-admin": "12.4.0", on the firebase console i enable only "Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)" and i use generated json with credentials to initialize app:
    const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

    const firebaseApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp (
      {
         credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert ({
             type: 'service_account',
             project_id: ...,
             private_key_id: ...,
             private_key: ...,
             client_email: ...,
             client_id: ...,
             auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
             token_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
             auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
             client_x509_cert_url: ...
         }),
         databaseURL: ...,
      },
      'app'
    );

    firebaseApp.messaging().sendToDevice(
      tokens, 
      {
        notification: {...},
        data: {...}
      }
    );

and as a result of the sendToDevice i have error mentioned above.
What i missing or doing wrong?

Consider filing an issue on the firebase-admin-node GitHub.

Issue that for now need to use sendEachForMulticast method - sendToDevice deprecated;

Solution :
The sendToDevice method is deprecated; Google now recommends using the send method instead.
The send method has been available since SDK version 6.0.0
Example usage:
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
    },
    data: {
        title: title,
    },
    token: pushToken
};

await firebase.messaging.send(message);

More information :
Below are the details regarding the new methods using Google's HTTP v1 API for messaging. This information is provided to help you transition to the new method using API v1:
Source click here

